# How to perform multiple regressions grouped by 2 factors and create a file containing N and R-squared?

Tags: r

I am running into some problems again and hope that someone can help me. I am doing research on the effect of ELI on ROS for firms and if the pandemic has an effect on this. For this research, my supervisor for my thesis has asked me to do a regression analysis per year grouped by industries (NAICS) and I am at a loss as to how to do this. I have firms in 46 different industries (NAICS) and 11 years of firm data per firm (2010-2020). Now I would like to run a regression `ROS ~ ELI + ELI*Pandemic`, for all industries for each year and then capture the resulting N (number of firms per industry) and R-squared in one file. The image below is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I hope that someone can help me because I am at an absolute loss and I can't seem to find a similar question/answer on SO.

Here is the `dput(head())` as an example. NAICS is the industry.

```
df <- structure(list(NAICS = c(315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315), 
        Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), 
        Firm = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
        ROS = c(0.17, 0.19, 0.29, 0.3, 0.29, 0.25), 
        ELI = c(0.856264428748774, 0.723379402777553, 0.958341156943977, 0.680567730897854, 0.790480861209701, 0.827279134948296), 
        Pandemic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
        row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
        class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Check my latest updates please.

Comment: N is working, but it seems that ELI:Pandemic still doesn't show up.

Comment: I think that's because your `Pandemic` values are mostly zero.

Comment: It works for you though, so that is weird.

Comment: Yes but values are all `NA`. I don't know I just put my latest solution here but you try by updating all of your packages first.

Comment: I feel like an idiot! That did the trick! Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Glad it finally solved your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update02**

I have made the necessary modifications on my solution after I received the original data set and I don't there will be any other problems.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)


df %>% 
  group_by(NAICS, Year) %>% 
  add_count(name = "N") %>%
  nest(data = !c(NAICS, Year, N)) %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~ lm(ROS ~ ELI + ELI * Pandemic, data = .)),
         glance = map(models, ~ glance(.x)),
         tidied = map(models, ~ tidy(.x))) %>%
  unnest(glance) %>%
  select(NAICS:N, r.squared, tidied) %>%
  unnest(tidied)


# A tibble: 2,024 x 9
# Groups:   NAICS, Year [506]
   NAICS  Year     N r.squared term         estimate std.error statistic     p.value
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>     <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1   315  2010    12     0.122 (Intercept)    0.0959    0.0123     7.83   0.0000143 
 2   315  2010    12     0.122 ELI            0.0189    0.0160     1.18   0.266     
 3   315  2010    12     0.122 Pandemic      NA        NA         NA     NA         
 4   315  2010    12     0.122 ELI:Pandemic  NA        NA         NA     NA         
 5   315  2011    12     0.129 (Intercept)    0.0999    0.0115     8.70   0.00000559
 6   315  2011    12     0.129 ELI            0.0161    0.0132     1.22   0.251     
 7   315  2011    12     0.129 Pandemic      NA        NA         NA     NA         
 8   315  2011    12     0.129 ELI:Pandemic  NA        NA         NA     NA         
 9   315  2012    13     0.594 (Intercept)   -0.486     0.606     -0.802  0.439     
10   315  2012    13     0.594 ELI            2.11      0.526      4.01   0.00205   
# ... with 2,014 more rows
```

Comment: This work for the R-squared although the count only gives a 1. But this is easily fixed in excel. Thank you so much for the speedy reply!.

Comment: Is there a simple way to add the coefficients of the regression? Or is that a lot harder to do?

Comment: Does it have to count the unique number of firm per industry or just number of firms per industry?

Comment: No it's quite easy. I'm editing my solution.

Comment: Yes the unique numbers of firms per industry per year. Sorry that I wasn't clear enough on that. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I hope this has fixed the count problem. Check it please and let me know.

Comment: It seems like it has fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: In case you would like to extract fitted values or maybe residuals you can make use of function `augment` from `broom` package the way I used `tidy` and `glance`. However, all of these have also base R solutions. My pleasure, You're welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232171/discussion-between-simba63-and-anoushiravan-r).

Comment: For some strange reason my computer crashed and now I get this error message: 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `glance`.
x object 'fstatistic' not found
i Input `glance` is `map(models, ~glance(.x))`.
i The error occurred in group 1: NAICS = 315, Year = 2010.

Comment: You did not receive this error before? There must have been a change in the code or something. Have you found the answer to `ELI * Pandemic` issue?

Comment: No unfortunately not. But I copied the code exactly like last time and didn't edit my dataframe. Strange.

Comment: Can you share more of your data? So that I can check it again.

Comment: I sent a message in the chat.